# How can I test the current carrier state for an ethernet adapter in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

In Arch Linux, how can I check if a network device (say `eth0`) has a carrier signal present?

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216458/on-linux-how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-a-nic-interface-is-enabled-and) Some more methods there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` is by far the easiest method.

Answer (score 5):

If you want that information and more in handy little commands:

```
mii-tool eth0
ethtool eth0
```

might do the job.